# Connecting to Mac Mini via SSH unreliable

Tags: network, mac-mini, ssh

More often than not I am getting this error when connecting to a brand new Mac Mini, firewall disabled:

```
ssh -l [username] [fixed_ip]
ssh: connect to host [fixed_ip] port 22: Connection timed out
ssh -l [username] [fixed_ip]
ssh: connect to host [fixed_ip] port 22: No route to host
```

(For security reasons, I have [fixed_ip] and [username] instead of the real values above.)

The connection does work sometimes, though. How can I make it more reliable?

Comment: The connection timed out and no route to host messages sounds like a DNS problem. Can you ping your Mac Mini by hostname and ip address? What happens when you try to ssh into the Mac Mini with "ssh username@hostname"?

Comment: What kind of machine are you using to ssh into the Mac Mini? Does the Mac Mini have two network connections active? i.e wifi and ethernet? Did you set a static IP address on the Mac Mini or was it assigned via DHCP? Can you ping another machine from the Mac Mini? Are you on a small home network with just one router or is it a larger network? What OS version is the Mac Mini running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved after disabling the screensaver and changing the energy saving options on the Mac Mini server.